# Find which field's size is greater than 20000 in a collection (mongodb)

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have this document in my collection and I need to find which field has value greater than 20000 for all documents like this. Some of fields are changing dynamically for the collection.

```
db.doors.find(
  {
    "doorseller": "e0asda9a0fqqf7-f0asdas66-48c4-bfe5-ssss", 
    "good.Derinlik.value" : {$exists:true}, 
     $where: "this.good.Derinlik.value.length > 20000" 
  }
)
```

This works but I also need to check other fields; however I don't want to manually write a query for each of them. Is there any method for this?
for example I want to check for

```
-runningStatus
-good.renkodu.value
```

And this documents are changing, their names for every document.

This is the sample document

```
  { 
        "doorseller" : "e0asda9a0fqqf7-f0asdas66-48c4-bfe5-ssss", 
        "_class" : "net.bowl.google.microservice.product.domain.Product", 
        "status" : "MATCHED", 
        "runningStatus" : "running_CREATED", 
        "hasValidImage" : true, 
        "doorID" : "3052007", 
        "door" : "4ef7a893-4158-4b4b-ba60-26cb9f75b988", 
        "good" : {
            "Ekipman ID" : {
                "value" : "", 
                "detail" : {
                    "revisedBy" : "door", 
                    "revisionDate" : ISODate("2017-02-07T10:13:34.615+0000")
                }, 
                "history" : [
                    {
                        "value" : "", 
                        "revisedBy" : "door", 
                        "revisionDate" : ISODate("2017-02-07T10:13:34.615+0000")
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            "Renk Kodu" : {
                "value" : "", 
                "detail" : {
                    "revisedBy" : "door", 
                    "revisionDate" : ISODate("2017-02-07T10:13:34.615+0000")
                }, 
                "history" : [
                    {
                        "value" : "", 
                        "revisedBy" : "door", 
                        "revisionDate" : ISODate("2017-02-07T10:13:34.615+0000")
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            "Malzeme" : {
                "value" : "", 
                "detail" : {
                    "revisedBy" : "door", 
                    "revisionDate" : ISODate("2017-02-07T10:13:34.615+0000")
                }, 
                "history" : [
                    {
                        "value" : "", 
                        "revisedBy" : "door", 
                        "revisionDate" : ISODate("2017-02-07T10:13:34.615+0000")
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            "doorID" : {
                "value" : "3052007", 
                "detail" : {
                    "revisedBy" : "admin", 
                    "revisionDate" : ISODate("2017-02-10T07:15:05.405+0000")
                }, 
                "history" : [
                    {
                        "value" : "3052007", 
                        "revisedBy" : "door", 
                        "revisionDate" : ISODate("2017-02-07T10:13:34.615+0000")
                    }, 
                    {
                        "value" : "3052007", 
                        "revisedBy" : "admin", 
                        "revisionDate" : ISODate("2017-02-10T07:15:05.405+0000")
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            "Garanti Notu" : {
                "value" : "", 
                "detail" : {
                    "revisedBy" : "door", 
                    "revisionDate" : ISODate("2017-02-07T10:13:34.615+0000")
                }, 
                "history" : [
                    {
                        "value" : "", 
                        "revisedBy" : "door", 
                        "revisionDate" : ISODate("2017-02-07T10:13:34.615+0000")
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            "Derinlik" : {
                "value" : "", 
                "detail" : {
                    "revisedBy" : "door", 
                    "revisionDate" : ISODate("2017-02-07T10:13:34.615+0000")
                }, 
                "history" : [
                    {
                        "value" : "", 
                        "revisedBy" : "door", 
                        "revisionDate" : ISODate("2017-02-07T10:13:34.615+0000")
                    }
                ]
            }
            }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest simple javascript code that you can run in the DBshell:

```
var keys = [];

db.doors.find({}).forEach(function(doc){
    for (var key in doc){ 
      if(typeof(doc[key]) == 'number' && doc[key] > 20000){
       keys.push({"doc.id": doc._id, "key":key, "value":doc[key]});
      }
    }
});
print(keys);   // prints all the results
```

> **Notes:**
>
> 1. The doc.id is an identifier of the specific doc when you have many documents.
> 2. The script above is good when the values are on the same depth (level 0).

Comment: It is not number. i want to check the length of string or whatever. and they are not in same level :(